# Adding a new executable to the PATH environment variable?

Tags: mac, install

I'm trying to install this library called phantomjs.

The instructions include this line:

> http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/BuildInstructions
>
> For convenience, copy the executable
>   bin/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs to some directory in your
>   PATH.

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think you'd need to worry about putting that in your path as bin is already in it. But if you wanted to, you can find how to achieve that here: http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm

Comment: @cksum but this is a relative path; we don't know what comes before the "bin".

Comment: @bneely Yes, but there is no ~/bin. The only locations are /bin, /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin. All of which are in your path already. If you run `path` you'll see the following by default: `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` I haven't look through the install script of the program in question, but it would be extremely unlikely to install into it's own 'bin' folder somewhere. And you can't add relative paths AFAIK. I'm inclined to think just a typo from a sloppy guide.

Comment: I know relative paths can't be added; I'm stating that the path in the question is a relative path because it doesn't start with a / or a ~ .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To find out what's in your PATH, open a Terminal window and run this command: `echo $PATH` . The output is a colon-separated list of directories, the contents of which you can run without specifying the full path.

Since /usr/bin is in my path, I can run the `w` command simply by typing `w` instead of the full `/usr/bin/w`.

Also, you don't have to move the executable into one of the listed PATH directories. Other options include

- Leave the executable where it is, and symlink to it from one of the PATH directories
- Add a directory to your PATH by explicitly setting it in a login script for your shell

Comment: Please, follow @Gerry's advice in the other answer, and **symlink** it. It is the cleanest way!

Comment: If, by any chance, you need a full directory in the `PATH`, for there are many executables in it you need access to, there isn't any other option and **that's** what the `PATH` is for. Currently we use the [~/.bash_profile to add to path](http://superuser.com/a/678147/28411).

Comment: Incase copying the binary fails. You might find [this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435256). The path to copy the binary to should be `usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 37):

The cleanest way to achieve this would be to symlink the binary in the /usr/local/bin directory (which is included in PATH by default). You might need to create this directory if it doesn't exist yet. You can check to see if these directories are already in your PATH by opening Terminal.app and typing:

`echo $PATH`

This will generate a colon delimited listing of all directories in your PATH.

If the directories /usr/local or /usr/local/bin do not exist yet, execute the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

Symlink the binary, replace (/Applications) with the path to phantomjs.app if it differs:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

Now you should have no problems executing phantomjs from the command-line.

Comment: +1, `ls /usr/local/bin/ || sudo mkdir  /usr/local/bin/ ; sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/bin/mysql`

Answer (score 4):

While symlinking the file from another directoy works, I prefer to actually copy/move the file to `usr/local/bin`, to not have it "twice".

```
cp bin/phantomjs.app/Contents/MacOS/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: cp makes a copy so you now have the file twice with no connection whilst link just has the one file but in two places

Answer (score 3):

Going back to the root of your issue, if you are installing phantomjs you can use npm to make it easier.

If you do then you can just run:

```
npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
```

which will install the binary inside of the proper bin directory.
(the -g flag indicates to npm that the package is to be installed globally)